# Kafka is not assigning a partition after Consumer.Poll(Duration.ZERO);

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i started a project where i implement appache kafka.
I already have a working producer that writes data into the queue. So far so good. Now i wanted to program an consumer that reads out all the data in the queue.
That is the corresponding code:

```
try {
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("names"));
    if (startingPoint != null){
        consumer.
        consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(0));
        consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
    }
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            keyValuePairs.add(new String[]{record.key(),record.value()});
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    consumer.close();
}
```

That code doesnt work right now like it is supposed to do. Only new records are consumed.
I was able to find out that
seekToBeginning() isn´t working because no partition is assigned to the consumer in that moment.
If i increase the duration of the poll it works. If i just pause the thread on the other hand it doesn´t.

Could someone please try to explain me why that is the case. I tried to find out by myself and already read something about a Kafka heartbeat. But i still haven´t fully understood what happens exactly.

Comment: You can use the deprecated `consumer.poll(0)`. This method waits for partition assignment before polling with a timeout. Unfortunately, the consumer interface does not expose the private method where you can provide Duration for timeout and explicitly specify if you want to wait for partition assignment or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment takes time; polling for 0 will generally mean the poll will exit before it occurs.

You should add a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` callback to the subscribe() method and perform the seek in `onPartitionsAssigned()`.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69121558Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69121558Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf, KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so69121558", "test");
            Consumer<String, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer("group", "");
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("so69121558"), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                    consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
                }

            });
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
            records.forEach(System.out::println);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            consumer.close();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69121558").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

Here are a couple of examples of doing it the Spring way - just add one of these (or both) to the above class.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "so69121558", topics = "so69121558")
void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> rec) {
    System.out.println(rec);
}

@KafkaListener(id = "so69121558-1", topics = "so69121558")
void pojoListen(String in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

The seeks are done a bit differently too; here's the complete example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69121558Application extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69121558Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69121558", topics = "so69121558")
    void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> rec) {
        System.out.println(rec);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69121558-1", topics = "so69121558")
    void pojoListen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69121558").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i would like to try that. Could you provide an codesample or give me an documentation where i can inform myself?

Comment: I added an example. Why did you tag the question with [tag:spring-kafka]? You are not using it; you are using the kafka API directly.

Comment: Oh i tried an example from the internet but implemented the whole thing into spring boot. I did not know that there would be also an spring-kafka librarie i found it now and will try it out. Are there differences i should notice? And i want say thank you already.
Could you tell me why i need to set the property to earliest?

Comment: spring-kafka provides a much simpler programming model, which will be familiar to Spring users that already use other messaging technologies such as RabbitMQ or JMS. `earliest` is required for the first time a consumer consumes from a topic/partition; by default, it's latest but, in your case, since we are performing `seekToBeginning` anyway, it's redundant; I just do it out of habbit; it wasn't needed here.

Comment: I added Spring examples.

Comment: Note that `onPartitionsAssigned` is also invoked on any other rebalancing after completing the initial subscriptions and first poll.